# Sybase Embedding Database

Tags: ios, database, mobile, sqlanywhere

I would like to know if its possible to embed a database into a mobile app, which uses sybase. I am informed this is not possible as the app needs to pair with the server first. My issue is that it takes too long on first run to download the data. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[SAP Sybase SQL Anywhere](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?docset=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.1/sqlanywhere_en12/help_top_index.htm&docSetID=1744) is an embedable database, that can be used in mobile applications.

Comment: Great thanks - i was going down this path so appreciate the response.

Comment: Is it possible to embed and then sync? using sql anywhere version 12.

Comment: I believe Mobilink is the piece that can be used for synchonization, but I've not worked with it.